# How to link com.android.Volley Package in JavaDoc

Tags: java, android, android-volley, javadoc

How would one go about linking to the volley package within a Javadoc?

Currently I am going about it as such:`{@link com.android.volley.Network}`, however this causes a reference not found error.

I've looked around for general solutions to this problem, but none seem to work in my case.

Relevant build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.4'
    testCompile files("${buildDir}/libs/resources.jar")
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/reports/javadoc/")
    failOnError false
}
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
task resourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = 'resources.jar'
    from files("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/androidTest/debug")
}
```

Comment: post the gradle file for that module

Comment: added the relevant pieces